# Eval ismember in a loop

Tags: matlab

I have 6 different arrays (double), with different sizes, called practice1, practice2, ..., practice6 and I need to compare each other to inspect whether they contain same numbers/values. I am trying to do a loop using the ismember and eval function such as below but I get the error "Undefined function 'eval' for input arguments of type 'logical". I would be grateful if someone could help me on how to do this!

```
allvariables = who('practice*')
for i=1:6
eval(ismember(allvariables{i}, allvariables{i+1}))
```

One other problem with my loop is that, as above, I am only comparing the current practice with the next one and not each practice with all the others. Probably there is a simpler way of doing this without a loop or a loop which covers all the possibilities?

Comment: I don't think that you need the `eval` command at all here. Can you just remove it? `ismember(allvariables{i}, allvariables{i+1}))`

Comment: No, it doesn't work because I need to compare the content of each array and allvariables = who('practice*') does not have the content.

Comment: I agree with @Pursuit. That's not how `eval` works and it's unnecessary here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see what's going on here. You need to either carefully construct your string, and then `eval` the whole thing, or `eval` the variable names and then call `ismember`.

Some examples are below:

```
%First some setup
practice_x= [1 2 3];
practice_y = [2 3 4];
practice_z = [1 4 5];
allvariables = who('practice*')
%    allvariables =
%      3×1 cell array
%        'practice_x'
%        'practice_y'
%        'practice_z'

%Option 1
for ix = 1:(length(allvariables)-1)
    eval(['ismember('  allvariables{ix} ', ' allvariables{ix+1} ')'])
end

%Option 1a (same as 1, but IMHO slightly easier to work with and explain on SO)
for ix = 1:(length(allvariables)-1)
    strTemp = ['ismember('  allvariables{ix} ', ' allvariables{ix+1} ')'];
    %When ix = 1, the strTemp variable contains the string below.
    %    strTemp =
    %    ismember(practice_x, practice_y)
    eval(strTemp )
end

%Option 2, use `eval` on the variable names directly
for ix = 1:(length(allvariables)-1)
    ismember(  eval(allvariables{ix}),   eval(allvariables{ix+1})   )
end

%For this example, all of these options result in the following output
%    ans =
%      1×3 logical array
%       0   1   1
%    ans =
%      1×3 logical array
%       0   0   1
```

*Standard Pedantic Admonition:*

Questions that involve storing information in variables names, forcing this type of manipulation of variable names as data, usually mean that the overall code is structured in a way that is, um, stressful and difficult to work with.

This works. This is consistent with Matlab's documented features. But somewhere in this code there are some strong anti-patterns with respect to how data is being handled and stored.